# Color for important entry in global TODO list

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In Org Agenda, I use Org priorities to know when I should get on something (A=now, B=soon or C=later).

I use `:STYLE:` property with a custom  `important` value for some entries (no matter when I need to do it).

I would like to color the line for such entries in the global TODO list in the agenda buffer.

I see no help in `:STYLE: habit` related customization.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to fontify all entries matching `:STYLE: important`.

```el
(defun fontify-important-entries ()
  ;; Move the point to the start of the buffer.
  (goto-char (point-min))
  ;; Then keep moving down one line until the end of the buffer.
  (while (progn (forward-line 1) (not (eobp)))
    ;; Now get the text property at the start of each line. If there
    ;; are no markers, do nothing.
    (when-let (marker (org-get-at-bol 'org-marker))
      (let* ((buffer (marker-buffer marker))
             (pos (marker-position marker))
             prop)
        ;; From the agenda buffer, move to the org file.
        (with-current-buffer buffer
          (widen) (goto-char pos)
          ;; The point is at the heading, so get the value of the
          ;; STYLE properties and set it to prop.
          (setq prop (org-entry-get nil "STYLE")))
        ;; Now move back to the agenda buffer and check if the value
        ;; of prop matches the string important.
        (when (string= prop "important")
          ;; If it does, change the face of that line/entry.
          (add-text-properties (point-at-bol)
                               (point-at-eol)
                               '(face org-habit-overdue-future-face)))))))

(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook 'fontify-important-entries)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that works great! Would you comment your code a bit to help me understand it and get to write the function myself next time? What would I need to change to set a color among colors used in org? I specifically don't understand the `add-text-properties` part… Also, I don't understand the `org-get-at-bol` part.

Comment: @teabow see the comments. I'm not sure I understand your second question. If you want to use a different color you can do so by replacing the `org-habit-overdue-future-face` face wtih something else.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I tried to change `org-habit-overdue-future-face` to something else such as `'(face :foreground "#FF0000")` (or simply `'(:foreground "#FF0000")`) but nothing happens (items color doesn't change).

Comment: It should be `'(face '(((:foreground "#FF0000"))))`

Comment: That's great, thank you! Really encouraging for learning some Elisp.